# How to prevent caching from jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

Could anyone please help me with this? I have a web page using .manifest for offline storage caching. In that page, I use jQuery ajax call to get the data from the server. If I first load the page, it is OK. I can switch between Online and Offline. But the problem is when I go back online and refresh the page. jQuery ajax cannot be able to talk to server anymore. Is there a way to for ajax to talk to the server or clear offline cache?

My ajax call is as such:

```
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",

            url: requestUrl,
            success: localSuccess,

            error: error,

            dataType: "text",
            cache:false
        });
```

Comment: I'm confused, why would you want to clear the offline cache if you can't access the server?

Comment: Kerry, I don't want to clear offline cache. I just want to sync my localStorage(HTML5 feature) with the server. But I cannot do the syncing if I allow the offline caching. Without that cache, it is working OK.

Answer (score 5):

I have this piece of code at the top of each page/Master page

```
    //Disable caching in IE, becuase it's EVIL!
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
```

Comment: I just wrote that but held off posting because 'cache:false' is already being passed as the last setting in the example given.

Comment: Thanks, Alastair. But I still cannot connect to the server. :(. I am now wondering if it is to do with browser cache.

Comment: @cynwong: Oops, didn't see the `cache:false` in the ajax call. Then my code won't help. Can you provide more details/more javascript in regards to the deciding between online/offline. I'm a little confused.

Comment: Alastair, I am detecting online/offline with navigator.onLine. I am using HTML5 localStorage feature. I would like to sync when it is online. So when offline, users will still be able to access the data and modify it if they want.

Answer (score 0):

put the random string into url like "get.php?random="+Math.random()" can solve this problem. It is not the best solution but It works great.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very very late to this party but just to put it out there. And I'm sorry to resurrect this question from Zombie land.
In safari and some older browsers, (from what I've experienced till now, `cache:false` doesn't seem to work sometimes). for a more cross browser compatible solution, you could add a data option to the ajax() call and add a random number generator as a parameter. It would be something like this.

```
 var callback = function () {
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: requestUrl,
      success: localSuccess,
      error: error,
      dataType: "text",

      //won't work sometimes
      cache:false,

      //start random number generator
      data : { r: Math.random() }
     //end random number generator
   });
  }
```

This way, everytime a server call happens, a new random number will be generated, and since the data is different from the previous requests, ajax requests wont be cached and will ensure a fresh server call every single time. And in your server, you could ignore this variable `r`.