# Prevent ajax caching in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I found similar questions connected with jQuery. My goal is to figure out how to prevent caching in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap (I use JSONP). I am making some ajax calls which dynamically fill the listview. I want to query web service each time I am initializing my page (pageinit). On my android device, after new query, data is added to the listview each time I go to the page. It does not delete and each time I visit the page I am adding a duplicate. I think it is connected with caching. I added something like this to my code:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
     });
});
```

It prevents from caching in my Chrome and Safari browsers, but it does not work on Android Device. How to prevent caching in Android devices?

PS. You may find this question similar, but not the same:
[How to prevent caching from jQuery Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002410/how-to-prevent-caching-from-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a random value from [Math.random](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) function and send it as a parameter every time you make an ajax request. It will always avoid cache.

```
var myRand = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html', para: myRand , 
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain it to me a little wider?

Comment: @Borewitsch Accept it as answer, if it served your purpose :D

Comment: I would, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem. I use jsonp and server does not accept such way of solving my problem. Do you know any other possibility which can be performed locally?