# Cannot retrieve server time from my jquery mobile app after calling a web service

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, web-services, jquery-mobile

I wanted to ask a general question regarding this issue because I do not know where I can find my issue in my code or app. I have a J Query mobile application that has a page retrieving the database server time by calling getDate in SQL. The sql execution to retrieve this time is passed in a C# web service developed in Visual Studio that returns a JSON string back tot he front end. To call the web service in C# the java script has a j Query $.post command to the given url containing the web service. If I run my app in a google chrome firefox browser everything is fine. The mobile app page retrieves the correct time and correct date. If I view this same content on a testing I Phone or I Pad the information I get is information I would have retrieved a few days ago or a few hours ago on my browser. I know this information may be too general but does anyone have a direction on where I should be looking at this specific issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a [caching problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3002410/901048). Code, please?

Comment: Yes, I agree.. sounds like a caching problem. Rather than use the jQuery POST method, you could try the .ajax(object) method and specify caching is turnt off... post some code for a little more help.

Comment: Thank you both for helping me out. The problem was a caching issue. I didn't update the timestamp when calling a post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari can be very aggressive with its caching. You can add a timestamp to your POST to overcome this by generating a unique invocation for each call.

```
 $.post("/MyService/", { timestamp: new Date().getTime() }, ...)
```