# jQuery: Caching prevents pages from loading correctly

Tags: jquery, caching, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with a website/application that I am developing. It is actually two problems with a common cause. I am using jQuery, jQueryMobile, and PHP.

1. I have a login system using sessions in PHP and a user types in a Username and Password and then logs in. On the next page, there is a check to make sure they are logged in as an authorized user (if they just use the URL, for instance) and a "Log Out" button. If they log out and try to access the page via the URL it denies access, however when the press "Log Out" it brings them to the login form and if they use the browser's Back button it will bring them back to the "logged in" page since it is cached.
2. I have dropdowns with a form submitted onChange and the form will do some stuff in PHP and then link them to another page with a header("location: site/page.php"). If the user presses the browser's Back button, the page is loaded from the cache and the current dropdown value is set to the one they selected previously. Now, to trigger the onChange event on that same option again they have to change the dropdown to the default "select one" option and then back to the one they want.

Both of these problems seem to result from caching. If there is an efficient fix for this I would love that but if I need to turn off caching I understand that will effect speed and that is ok for now. I tried turning the caching off by using this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/themes/CLIPTheme.css" />
    <script language="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.ajaxSetup ({
            // Disable caching of AJAX responses
            cache: false
    });
    </script>
```

...but that is not working. If anybody can help me I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully following the cause of your issue but I have found Safari to be very agressive with its caching. Consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13365356/64262

You don't include your ajax calls but I have needed to resort to this at times.

`$.post("/MyService/", { timestamp: new Date().getTime() }, ...)`

I can quote myself right?