# how to make javascript load new data every time (without using cache data) when I redirect it to a handler(page) on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, caching

I am initializing a download on click of a button.
The problem is that for the first time the request type is `200` (loading for the first time) and when I click on the download again its taking the data from cache (`304 request type`)
I need to make it load new data every time and disable cache. How can I achieve this??

currently I use

```
 $("#downloadbutton").live("click", function () {
window.location = "Handlers/somename.ashx?value="+somevalue+"&xxxxx="+$(".someid").text();
```

on button live click function.  I am fine if we can avoid the same using ajax call(cache:false).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002410/how-to-prevent-caching-from-jquery-ajax

Comment: No I dont think that will solve my issue
In that case the cache data is coming even after giving giving cache false in **AJAX** call
I am not doing any ajax calls here and its just 'javascript' button click which is gonna call a handler that will return some document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a random number to the querystring of the file you are calling in the click event. This should trigger the browser to reload rather than use cache as you are tricking it to think it's a new page request.

Example:

```
 $("#downloadbutton").live("click", function () {
var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
window.location = "Handlers/somename.ashx?value="+somevalue+"&xxxxx="+$(".someid").text() + "ts=" + timestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks :D It solves the problem though its not technically specifying that cache should not be loaded anywhere !!

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to target page,  you can use following meta tags in target page to disable  caching.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />    
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
</head>
```

Comment: But this will disable cache for the entire page which might bring down the performance as load time will increase. Can we disable cache only for that button click? can we do the page redirection in ajax-jquery? so that we can specify cache:false for the particular request

Comment: Can Handlers/somename.ashx output cache control headers? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970938/ideal-http-cache-control-headers-for-different-types-of-resources